# Using gsutil rsync to update contents of a static website served from a Google Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rsync, gsutil

I have a personal static website, [www.kurtpeek.com](http://www.kurtpeek.com), that I'm serving from a Google Bucket (cf. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website). In order to quickly make updates on my local directory visible on the website, I'd like to use `gsutil`'s `rsync` command.

For example, I've made some changes to `index.html` and then run this command:

```
~/Google Drive/webpage$ gsutil rsync -d . gs://www.kurtpeek.com
Building synchronization state...
Starting synchronization
Copying file://./.DS_Store [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
Copying mtime from src to dst for gs://www.kurtpeek.com/CV_Kurt_Peek_September_2017.pdf
Copying mtime from src to dst for gs://www.kurtpeek.com/confirmation.html
Copying file://./index.html [Content-Type=text/html]...
| [2 files][ 19.1 KiB/ 19.1 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 2 objects/19.1 KiB.
```

However, if I then navigate to www.kurtpeek.com and do 'view source', I see that the changes have not appeared, even if I refresh the page.

Can someone explain why this is not working?

Comment: The version that is being served is from a cache. You may want to lower the value as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control however, that's an example using `gcloud cp`, not sure how that works with `rsync`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [Robert Lacok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6933420/robert-lacok), the content was being served from the cache. Clearing my history or just viewing it in a different browser showed the changes.